# c++ combine path of file as a string with file name

Tags: c++

I want to read some input files in my c++ code and I want to define the path of input files as a string and then combine it with file names. How can I do this? (Input_path + filename.dat)

Comment: Add your code you have so far.

Comment: A way is combining before calling ifstream (combine in ifstream is not possible). It worked well. Anyway thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would use something like:

```
string path ("yourFilePath");
string filename ("filename");
```

You could then open the file like this:

```
ifstream inputFileStream;
inputFileStream.open(path + fileName);
```

Depending on your requirements, you will have to decide whether to use formatted or unformatted input when reading. I would read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/76640/) for more information regarding that.

Cocatenation referenced from: [C++ string concatenation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/)
Reading referenced from: [C++ read and write with files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Comment: `string name; // To hold the file name

//Write the path of the folder in which your file is placed
string path = "C:\\Users\\Faisal\\Desktop\\Programs\\";
cout << "Enter the file name: ";

getline(cin, name);// Open the file.


file.open(path + name.c_str());// Test for errors.`

Comment: I am getting error `[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::basic_string<char>)`

Comment: This answer is now out-of-date. See Vlad's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68504328/421178

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <filesystem> //C++ 17
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string dir("c:\\temp");
    string fileName("my_file.txt");
    
    fs::path fullPath = dir;
    fullPath /= fileName;
    cout << fullPath.c_str() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try any of these codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main() {

  std::string filepath = "D:/location/";
  filepath+= "filename.dat";
  std::ifstream fp;
  fp.open(filepath.c_str(),std::ios_base::binary);

  ....PROCESS THE FILE HERE
  fp.close();

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main() {

   std::string filepath = "D:/location/";
  std::ifstream fp;
  fp.open((filepath+"filename.dat").c_str(),std::ios_base::binary);

 ...............

  fp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

or use `std::string::append`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int main() {

 std::string filepath = "D:/location/";
  std::ifstream fp;
  fp.open((filepath.append("filename.dat")).c_str(),std::ios_base::binary);



  fp.close();
  return 0;
}
```